# Is $DSPACE(f) \subseteq DTIME(f)$ always?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, space-complexity

Is $DSPACE(f) \subseteq DTIME(f)$ always?

For example, if we have a language $A\in DSPACE(log^2(n))$ can we say that $A\in P$ (and  subsequently in NP and coNP) since $DSPACE(log^2(n))\subseteq DSPACE(n^3) \subseteq DTIME(n^3)$?

I know about $ DTIME(f) \subseteq DSPACE(f) \subseteq DTIME(2^{O(f)})$ but $DTIME(2^{O(f)})$ is too big in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We don't know that $\mathrm{DSPACE}[f(n)]\subseteq\mathrm{DTIME}[f(n)]$ is *ever* true and we suspect that it's never true.

A Turing machine that uses space $f(n)$ can run for $2^{O(f(n))}$ steps without getting stuck in an infinite loop, so it should be able to do much more than a Turing machine that can only run for $f(n)$ steps.  As you've observed, if $\mathrm{DSPACE}[f(n)]\subseteq\mathrm{DTIME}[f(n)]$, then $\mathrm{DSPACE}[f(n)]=\mathrm{DTIME}[f(n)]$ and we have no reason to think that would ever be true for reasonable functions.

Comment: So it's an open question? is it related to P=NP? like if $\mathrm{DSPACE}[f(n)]\subseteq\mathrm{DTIME}[f(n)]$ then P=NP?

Comment: @kuhaku, it depends on $f(n)$. If it is polynomial, then - yes, it will imply $\mathsf{P = NP}$.

Comment: You use Savitch to prove that @rus9384?

Comment: @kuhaku, padding argument, and the fact that $\mathsf{NTIME(f(n)) \subseteq DSPACE(f(n))}$. I'm not sure if last is true for every $f(n))$, but surely it is for polynomials and larger functions.

Comment: @rus9384 No, Savitch is for proving things about nondeterministic space classes; everything here is deterministic.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, well, he asked about NP which is non-deterministic, but Savitch's theorem is about space, not time. However, yes, we need to use Savitch theorem in that case.